# Text size in decorate path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use this code to generate text along a path (here, a simple circular path):

```
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- QUELQUES TEXTES

\path [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={Tympan d'un astrolabe dans lequel les lignes horaires in{\'e}gales de 1{$^{\text{{\`e}re}}$} esp{\`e}ce
sont des cassiniennes {\`a} 1 p{\^o}le},text align=fit to path,pre length=2em, post length=2em},decorate}]  { (175:\RCapricorne+.15) arc (175:5:\RCapricorne+.15) } ;

\path [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={D. Collin {\copyright} {$2012$}},text align=center},decorate}]   { (200:\RCapricorne+.35) arc (200:228:\RCapricorne+.35) } ;

\path [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={Latitude: {$43^{\circ} 43^{\prime}$} N.},text align=fit to path,pre length=2em, post length=2em},decorate}]     { (252:\RCapricorne+.35) arc (252:290:\RCapricorne+.35) } ;
```

But I do not know how to change the text size inside this postaction procedure. For example, as the first text is quite long, I want to resize the text. So it is possible? And in what way?

Ci-dessous le code utilisé.
Rien n'est optimal car je suis un néophyte de TikZ.

(Here the code in use.
Nothing is optimal under this code, because I'm just a newer in TikZ...)

```
   % Tracé complet  du tympan d'un astrolabe planisphérique
    % Author: Dominique COLLIN
    %==============================================================================================
    % MATERIEL :
    % COMPILATION : nécessite un système Tex complet installé sur le disque dur.
    %   Tex Live 2012 pour macintosh intel. (http://www.tug.org/mactex/)
    %   pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
    %   LaTeX2e version < 2011/06/27 >
    %   TikZ and PGF sont des packages TeX pour la création de graphiques et dessins programmables.
    %   PGF 2012-05-18 CVS build.
    %   GNUPLOT version 4.4 patchlevel 3 pour macintoh intel
    %   Manuel TikZ = http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-05-18.pdf
    %   TeXample.net is a web site dedicated to the wonderful world of TeX and friends.
    %   EDITEUR DE TEXTE = TexShop Version 3.11 pour macintosh Intel. (http://www.texshop.org)
    % ==============================================================================================
    %\documentclass[9pt]{article}%           autres choix : report, book
    \documentclass[8pt,article]{memoir}
    %\documentclass[8pt]{standalone}
    % ==============================================
        \usepackage{etex}%
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[utf8,applemac]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}
        \usepackage{mathrsfs,bm}
        \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd}
        \usepackage{comment,relsize}
        \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
        % ==============================================
        \usepackage[babel=true,kerning=true]{microtype}%pour le package tikZ et les deux points``:''
        % ------- TikZ packages.
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,fit,through,intersections}
        \usetikzlibrary{decorations} % LATEX and plain TEX when using TikZ
        \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}% texte le long d'un chemin....
        \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
        %
        %\pagestyle{empty}
            % ==============================================
    \begin{comment}
    :Title: Tracé du tympan d'un Astrolabe planisphérique
    :Tags: mathematical engine;geometry;mathematics;ancient astronomy
    :Author: Dominique COLLIN
    :Slug: astrolabe
    \end{comment}
    % -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    \begin{document}
    % -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round, scale=1]
    % ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   ---
    % DEFINITIONS DES CONSTANTES / PARAMETRES MODIFIABLES
    %  (Define a few constants for easy configuration and computation)
    % ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- 
        \pgfmathparse{ 43 + 43/60 +50/3600 }
    \let\latitude\pgfmathresult% Latitude du lieu
    % --
        \pgfmathparse{ 23 + 26/60 }
    \let\epsilon\pgfmathresult% Déclinaison du soleil au solstice d'été
    % --
    \def\rayon{2}% Rayon de la sphère céleste servant à la projection stéréographique
    % ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   ---
    % CALCULS INITIAUX ET DIVERS
    % ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- 
    % -- Les rayons des cercles principaux, des colures des solstices, longueur des divers segments...
        \pgfmathparse{ -cot(\latitude) }
    \let\K\pgfmathresult% Constante pour le calcul de l'arc semi-diurne
        \pgfmathparse{ 2*\rayon*tan((180-\latitude)/2) + 2*\rayon*tan(\latitude/2) }
    \let\RHorizon\pgfmathresult% Rayon du cercle horizon
        \pgfmathparse{ 2*\rayon*tan((90-\epsilon)/2) }
    \let\RCancer\pgfmathresult% Rayon du colure d'ete
        \pgfmathparse{ 2*\rayon*tan((90+\epsilon)/2) }
    \let\RCapricorne\pgfmathresult% Rayon du colure d'hiver
        \pgfmathparse{ 2*\rayon*tan((180-\latitude)/2) }
    \let\Rmax\pgfmathresult% Rayon maximal de l'Astrolabe (ou limite des hectémories)
        \pgfmathparse{ 2*\rayon*tan(\latitude/2) }
    \let\Rmin\pgfmathresult% Rayon minimal de l'Astrolabe
        \pgfmathparse{ (\RCapricorne+\RCancer)/2 }
    \let\REcliptique\pgfmathresult% Rayon du cercle de l'écliptique
        \pgfmathparse{ \RHorizon/2-2*\rayon*tan(\latitude/2) }
    \let\yHorizon\pgfmathresult% Ordonnée du centre du cercle horizon
        \pgfmathparse{ \rayon*(1/tan((\latitude+90)/2)-tan((\latitude-90)/2))) }
    \let\yZenith\pgfmathresult% Ordonnée du Zénith
        \pgfmathparse{ -2*\rayon*tan((90+\latitude)/2) }
    \let\yNadir\pgfmathresult% Ordonnée du Nadir
        \pgfmathparse{ -\epsilon+\epsilon/100 }%
    \let\pas\pgfmathresult% Pour créer un pas en déclinaison dans l'intervalle [-epsilon;+epsilon].
    % ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   ---
% TRACES DES CERCLES, DES COURBES ET DES SEGMENTS
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- 
\begin{scope}% usage de "scope" afin de limiter l'effet de la commande \clip sur le reste de la figure générale
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\clip circle(\RCapricorne+1/150); % limitations de tous les tracés à l'intérieur du cercle du tropique du Capricorne (Hiver)
% -- -- -- 
%\draw [color=black] (0,0) circle(\Rmax); % Cercle maximal
%\draw [color=blue] (0,0) circle(\Rmin); % Cercle minimal
\draw [color=black] (0,0) circle(\RCancer); % Cercle du solstice d'été
\draw [color=black] (0,0) circle(\RCapricorne); % Cercle du solstice d'hiver
\draw [color=red] (0,0) circle(2*\rayon); % Cercle de l'équateur
\draw [color=black] (0, \yHorizon ) circle(\RHorizon/2); % Cercle de l'horizon du lieu
%\draw [color=green] (0, \REcliptique-\RCancer ) circle(\REcliptique); % Cercle de l'écliptique
% -- -- --
\draw [ ] (0,-\RCapricorne)--(0,\RCapricorne);% Méridien (ligne nord-sud)
\draw [ ] (-\RCapricorne,0)--(\RCapricorne,0);% ligne Est-Ouest
% -- -- --
\coordinate (H0) at (0, \RHorizon-\Rmax); % Centre du cercle horizon
\coordinate (Zenith) at (0, \yZenith);% Zénith
\coordinate (Nadir) at (0, \yNadir);% Nadir
% -- -- --
\fill [black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt); % Marquage de l'origine, centre du tympan
%\fill [black] (H0) circle (2pt); % Marquage du centre du cercle horizon
\fill [black] (Zenith) circle (1.5pt); % Marquage du Zéntih
%\fill [black] (Nadir) circle (3pt); % Marquage du Nadir
\end{scope}
%-----------------
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- QUELQUES TEXTES
\path [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={Tympan d'un astrolabe dans lequel les lignes horaires in{\'e}gales de 1{$^{\text{{\`e}re}}$} esp{\`e}ce
sont des cassiniennes {\`a} 1 p{\^o}le},text align=fit to path,pre length=2em, post length=2em},decorate}]  { (175:\RCapricorne+.15) arc (175:5:\RCapricorne+.15) } ;
\path [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={D. Collin {\copyright} {$2012$}},text align=center},decorate}]   { (200:\RCapricorne+.35) arc (200:228:\RCapricorne+.35) } ;
\path [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={Latitude: {$43^{\circ} 43^{\prime}$} N.},text align=fit to path,pre length=2em, post length=2em},decorate}]     { (252:\RCapricorne+.35) arc (252:290:\RCapricorne+.35) } ;
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\end{tikzpicture}
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\end{document}
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).  It's also a good idea to include a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which shows all the packages/libraries that you're using so others don't have to guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside `text=` you can use the standard font switches or `\fontsize{}{}\selectfont` within the (customizable) delimiters `|`:

```
    \documentclass[8pt,article]{memoir}

        \usepackage{etex}%
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[utf8,applemac]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}
        \usepackage{mathrsfs,bm}
        \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd}
        \usepackage{comment,relsize}
        \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

        \usepackage[babel=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,fit,through,intersections}
        \usetikzlibrary{decorations} % LATEX and plain TEX when using TikZ
        \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}% texte le long d'un chemin....
        \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round, scale=1]

        \pgfmathparse{ 43 + 43/60 +50/3600 }
    \let\latitude\pgfmathresult% Latitude du lieu
    % --
        \pgfmathparse{ 23 + 26/60 }
    \let\epsilon\pgfmathresult% Déclinaison du soleil au solstice d'été
    % --
    \def\rayon{2}% Rayon de la sphère céleste servant à la projection stéréographique

        \pgfmathparse{ -cot(\latitude) }
    \let\K\pgfmathresult% Constante pour le calcul de l'arc semi-diurne
        \pgfmathparse{ 2*\rayon*tan((180-\latitude)/2) + 2*\rayon*tan(\latitude/2) }
    \let\RHorizon\pgfmathresult% Rayon du cercle horizon
        \pgfmathparse{ 2*\rayon*tan((90-\epsilon)/2) }
    \let\RCancer\pgfmathresult% Rayon du colure d'ete
        \pgfmathparse{ 2*\rayon*tan((90+\epsilon)/2) }
    \let\RCapricorne\pgfmathresult% Rayon du colure d'hiver
        \pgfmathparse{ 2*\rayon*tan((180-\latitude)/2) }
    \let\Rmax\pgfmathresult% Rayon maximal de l'Astrolabe (ou limite des hectémories)
        \pgfmathparse{ 2*\rayon*tan(\latitude/2) }
    \let\Rmin\pgfmathresult% Rayon minimal de l'Astrolabe
        \pgfmathparse{ (\RCapricorne+\RCancer)/2 }
    \let\REcliptique\pgfmathresult% Rayon du cercle de l'écliptique
        \pgfmathparse{ \RHorizon/2-2*\rayon*tan(\latitude/2) }
    \let\yHorizon\pgfmathresult% Ordonnée du centre du cercle horizon
        \pgfmathparse{ \rayon*(1/tan((\latitude+90)/2)-tan((\latitude-90)/2))) }
    \let\yZenith\pgfmathresult% Ordonnée du Zénith
        \pgfmathparse{ -2*\rayon*tan((90+\latitude)/2) }
    \let\yNadir\pgfmathresult% Ordonnée du Nadir
        \pgfmathparse{ -\epsilon+\epsilon/100 }%
    \let\pas\pgfmathresult% Pour créer un pas en déclinaison dans l'intervalle [-epsilon;+epsilon].
    % ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   ---
% TRACES DES CERCLES, DES COURBES ET DES SEGMENTS
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- ---  ---   ---   ---   --- 
\begin{scope}% usage de "scope" afin de limiter l'effet de la commande \clip sur le reste de la figure générale
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\clip circle(\RCapricorne+1/150); % limitations de tous les tracés à l'intérieur du cercle du tropique du Capricorne (Hiver)
% -- -- -- 
%\draw [color=black] (0,0) circle(\Rmax); % Cercle maximal
%\draw [color=blue] (0,0) circle(\Rmin); % Cercle minimal
\draw [color=black] (0,0) circle(\RCancer); % Cercle du solstice d'été
\draw [color=black] (0,0) circle(\RCapricorne); % Cercle du solstice d'hiver
\draw [color=red] (0,0) circle(2*\rayon); % Cercle de l'équateur
\draw [color=black] (0, \yHorizon ) circle(\RHorizon/2); % Cercle de l'horizon du lieu
%\draw [color=green] (0, \REcliptique-\RCancer ) circle(\REcliptique); % Cercle de l'écliptique
% -- -- --
\draw [ ] (0,-\RCapricorne)--(0,\RCapricorne);% Méridien (ligne nord-sud)
\draw [ ] (-\RCapricorne,0)--(\RCapricorne,0);% ligne Est-Ouest
% -- -- --
\coordinate (H0) at (0, \RHorizon-\Rmax); % Centre du cercle horizon
\coordinate (Zenith) at (0, \yZenith);% Zénith
\coordinate (Nadir) at (0, \yNadir);% Nadir
% -- -- --
\fill [black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt); % Marquage de l'origine, centre du tympan
%\fill [black] (H0) circle (2pt); % Marquage du centre du cercle horizon
\fill [black] (Zenith) circle (1.5pt); % Marquage du Zéntih
%\fill [black] (Nadir) circle (3pt); % Marquage du Nadir
\end{scope}
%-----------------
% ---  ---   ---   ---   --- QUELQUES TEXTES
\path [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={|\tiny|Tympan d'un astrolabe dans lequel les |\Large|lignes horaires in{\'e}gales de 1{$^{\text{{\`e}re}}$} esp{\`e}ce
sont des |\small|cassiniennes {\`a} 1 p{\^o}le},text align=fit to path,pre length=2em, post length=2em},decorate}]  { (175:\RCapricorne+.15) arc (175:5:\RCapricorne+.15) } ;
\path [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={D. Collin {\copyright} {$2012$}},text align=center},decorate}]   { (200:\RCapricorne+.35) arc (200:228:\RCapricorne+.35) } ;
\path [postaction={decoration={text along path, text={Latitude: {$43^{\circ} 43^{\prime}$} N.},text align=fit to path,pre length=2em, post length=2em},decorate}]     { (252:\RCapricorne+.35) arc (252:290:\RCapricorne+.35) } ;
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\end{tikzpicture}
% -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent ! I use your modification code in text in decoration, and I obtain exactely that I want (and research)! Thank you very much !

Comment: @DominiqueCOLLIN Glad I could help! Don't forget to up-vote and accept my answer (the checkmark below the vote count, to the left).